# regex javascript pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate with javascript, a textbox with this format: 99/99999999/99
I've done a function that solves the problem. But I'd like to improved using Regex, but I'm new with regex. Any suggestion please?

This is how I maked before:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RevNass" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="NASS inválido. Formato correcto: ##/########/##" Display="None"
ValidationExpression="^\d{2}/\d{8}/\d{2}$"
ControlToValidate="TextBox1" meta:resourceKey="RevNass"/>

<asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="RevNass_ValidatorCalloutExtender" 
runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RevNass">
</asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

But I need to validated only with javascript in the onblur event, but i don't know how to convert this pattern "^\d{2}/\d{8}/\d{2}$" to javascript's pattern. I'm Sorry but this is urgent no time to readed a hugh tutorial, later i will.

Comment: Yes, have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/. The expression that matches this pattern is not difficult and you should be able to create it after reading the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{8}\/[0-9]{2}$/` is a regex matching your pattern, assuming `9` can be any digit.

`/^\d{2}\/\d{8}\/\d{2}$/` would work, too, but I usually prefer writing `[0-9]` as you immediately see what it's doing on a quick look at the regex.

Comment: You should anchor the regex, unless it will match `abc99/99999999/99def`

Comment: Done, completely forgot that ;o

Comment: Thanks!! I finally do this:                                    function myFuncion(tb) {
        var re = new RegExp(/^\d{2}\/\d{8}\/\d{2}$/);
        if (tb.value.match(re)) {
            tb.style.border = "1px solid #cccccc";
        }
        else{
            tb.style.border = "1px solid red";
            tb.title = "NASS inválido";
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

It's practically the same, you just need to enclose the regex in forward slashes

`/^\d{2}\/\d{8}\/\d{2}$/`